# Just can't get rid of `&#13;` characters from html string

Tags: php, string

This is the string, which I am trying to clean up.

```
 '&#13;        &#13;    <span>CR - CROPLAND</span>&#13;'
```

This is my calling statement:

```
 trim(strip_tags(clean_string($leftTd->innerhtml())))
```

This is the function I tried to clean it up with, but it does not work.

```
 function clean_string($string){
   for($control = 0; $control < 32; $control++) {
      $string = str_replace(chr($control), "", $string) ;
   }
   return $string ;
}
```

I also tried :

```
 // $string = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9\-\./,']", " ",$string) ;
```

, but it does not work.

Help!
Specifically I am trying to get rid of `&#13;`. what exactly is it. Googling does not help\

Thanks

Comment: Ascii 0x13, or 19: [(XOFF, with XON is TERM=18 flow control)](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running replacement, decode the [HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-entities/info) with [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

```
function clean_string($string){
   $string = html_entity_decode($string);
   //replace here
   return $string ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to search for the string "`&#13;`", as it is literally printed like that.  It has yet to be translated into the special character it represents.

```
str_replace("&#13;", "", $string);
```

or more usefully:

```
function clean_string($string){
   for($control = 0; $control < 32; $control++) {
      $string = str_replace("&#$control;", "", $string) ;
   }
   return $string ;
}
```

Note: Character 13 is apparently a "Vertical tab"... Interesting. http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`html_entity_decode();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
$output = html_entity_decode($input);
```